# How to initialize configurable product details by variant's id in URL

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have my Magento store configured to autoselect a variant by the url parameters via the Javascript method that has been posted as a solution to this issue on similar questions before. However, this method does not initialize the page with the values (name, price, image) of the variant. It instead loads the configurable product details page and then a split second after, selects the product variant via javascript. For my purposes, I'd like to have the configurable product details page load with all relevant values set to the variants values from the server. That is, without javascript. How can I accomplish this?

An example of how this would function:

- User visits `mystore.com/product?variant=733` (where 733 is the simple product id)
- Page retrieves configurable product with name and price set to the values of the variant with product id 733. (this should be done on the server side not the client side)
- appropriate swatch options are preselected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the product and it's price/name like this:

```
$variant = $this->getRequest()->getParam('variant');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($variant);
$price = $product->getPrice();
$name = $product->getName();
```